# How to get a real dendogram from networkx's Louvain community detection algorithm?

Tags: networkx

A real dendogram is a tree where you should be able to decide the number of partitions you want. But for some reason the networkx's own [implemetation](https://python-louvain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) only return "the best partition". So if the algorithm thinks that the best partition consist of four different communities, then this partition is also on the second highest level of the dendogram.

Theoretically it is possibly to select the number of communities with Louvain, but the current implementations do not allow that. Is there any nice trick how to overcome this, or do I really need to invent the wheel again and implement it myself from the scratch?

Answer (score 0):

The Louvain dendrogram can be accessed through [community.generate_dendrogram](https://readthedocs.org/projects/python-louvain/downloads/pdf/latest/), and should have all partition mergers up until the optimal partition (i.e. any further mergers would decrease modularity).  The networkx louvain is based on the [python-louvain](https://github.com/taynaud/python-louvain/tree/master/community) package on GitHub, so you can follow further issues and discussions there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In that manual, it also says: A dendrogram is a tree and each level is a partition of the graph nodes.  Level 0 is the first partition, whichcontains the smallest communities, and the best is len(dendrogram) - 1.  The higher the level is, the bigger are the communities. 

The optimal partition might not be two communities, but what if I want to force it to find "the best partition with two commuinites". Basically, I want to finish the dendogram to the top.